# How to find and calculate correlation in a data set which has categorical and continuous variables?

Tags: python, correlation

I am working on an Insurance domain use case to predict if an existing customer will buy a second insurance policy or not. I have a few personal details of the customer under different categories like Marital status, Smoker (Yes or No), Age (Young, Adult, Senior Citizen), Gender (Male/Female) and few are continuous variables like Premium Paid, Sum Insured.

My target is to use this mix set of categorical and continuous variables and predict the class ( 1 - Will buy a second policy, 0 - Will not buy a second policy). So how can I find/compute the correlation in this dataset and pick only the significant ones to use in Logistic Regression formula for classification?

Will appreciate if someone can provide articles, link to a similar piece of work done in Python.

Answer (score 0):

For this problem, buy a second policy is more of a probabilistic event rather than a deterministic one. For example, **how likely your customer A will buy another insurance** and not **customer A will not buy it**

First, you need to have an hypothesis. Buy a second policy is your dependent variable (as the name say, it will **depend** of the values from other variables); this is the Y of your equation. Which factors do you belive that will lead a customer to acquire another policy?

Based on your experience in insurance field, you may say that customers older than X or who have been client for more than Y years, from gender Z and so on. These are your independend variables - the X of your equation.

If you really want to work with Python for this, check https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html#ordinary-least-squares but if it was me, I would start on Excel and if things get more complex, switch to Python.

For your categorical data, you can assign values for them... like Gender 1 for Male and 0 for Female. Check this link for more information https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#encoding-categorical-features

Comment: My data is transactional in nature, so I have done a bit of feature engineering. I have grouped policy count for each customer and gave it a resultant class of 1 if policy count is greater than 1 else the class is marked 0. With this approach, I classified each customer as to which class he belongs. On this data, I am applying logistic regression to predict in which of either class a customer will fall into. I am a newbie in data science, please suggest if my approach can be improvised. Yes, I am using One Hot Encoding for the categorical variables.